# TFS : Get Files of a Change set before making changes further

Tags: tfs

Say, I have Change Set A under which I have checked in 10 files FileA1,FileA2..FileA10. I am going to make changes further in any of those above file that I am not even sure. So, I need to have a copy of the files in Change Set A , physically in some directory say **C:\ChangeSetAFiles** and proceed with changes. In case my new changes are wrong it will be easy for me to detect.

Please help me out.

I can do this easily in Tortoise SVN to export a set of files to any location I need.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options once you've checked in the changeset.

- Either you don't check in the changes until you are completely happy with them
- Or you can shelve the changes, which add them to source control but aren't available to anyone else until the are checked in.

If required you can undo the check out or check in the changes with the shelveset. Whatever you do, you can always rollback your changes by the changeset number if they get checked in and cause an issue.

Comment: Fine with this... I have to extract those files and move it to another location .. is it possible... Wat can I do is manually prepare the folder structure and put files in them. Is ther any way that I can automate to do this!

Comment: You can keep everything under source control. You just need to shelve the changes you've worked on that are incomplete. After this point you can "get latest" source code  to get the original/checked in working code or you can get the shelved changes by the shelveset number.

Comment: For eg. I have following CGSETA,CGSETB,... I want to get all the files in CGSETA and get it copied to another folder location... I don think it is possible... Thats wat I want... It can be done in Sub Version..Thats y I expected it from TFS.

Comment: I think you can only achieve this by manually copying the files from your file system with TFS, unless you change your entire working folder. However, I maintain what I previously said about shelving the changeset. You can the retrieve the shelved files and merge in any changes if required and rollback files if otherwise, that's one of the benefits of source control.

Comment: Our team has created an app to do! Kudos to them... Thanks all for  your suggestions...